# Are all renderers good for textures?

Tags: three.js

So, the scene include an earth spinning on its axis, a moon rotating around the earth, and a light source to the right that will help to simulate the effect of an eclipse. I thought it would be easy because we've done shadows and transformations before but I ran into a problem.

In our template we have the following at the top:

```
// For the assignment where a texture is required you should
// deactivate the Detector and use ONLY the CanvasRenderer. There are some
// issues in using waht are called Cross Domain images for textures. You
// can get more details by looking up WebGL and CORS using Google search. 
// if ( Detector.webgl )
    // var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
// else
    var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

My problem is, when I leave it like that, the spotlight doesn't appear on the scene. However, as was warned, if I activate the `Detector`, the textures won't work.

But I need both textures and the spotlight. How do I work around this?

Comment: If this is an assignment, you should most probably ask the one who wrote the template.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing yourself. Detector.webgl only checks for support of WebGL on the browser. The code below uses the WebGL renderer if the current browser supports WebGL and CanvasRenderer if there is no WebGL support.

```
   if ( Detector.webgl )
       var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     else
       var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

With WebGL - loading textures will run into a cross domain issue. Best to then execute the code either on a web server or a local server like http://www.wampserver.com/en/ for Windows or https://www.mamp.info/en/ for Mac. Or npm-package like https://github.com/tapio/live-server.

As far as I know shadows are not supported on the CSSCanvasRender. I would ask your assignment head to clarify.